# php upload file and move to server

Tags: php

I want to upload files from my server. I had written this piece of code months ago when it worked fine, but now I have no idea what's going wrong.

I basically want to move the file to a folder "uploads" in my server and then store the path in the database.

The uploaded file doesn't get reflected in the database.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    require("dbconn.php");
    $filename = $_POST['filename'];
    $name = $filename . "." . pathinfo($_FILES['ufile']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    //$name = $_FILES['ufile']['name'];
    //$size = $_FILES['file']['size']
    //$type = $_FILES['file']['type']

    $tmp_name = $_FILES['ufile']['name']; //was tmp_name
    $error = $_FILES['ufile']['error'];
    if(isset($name)) 
    {
        if(!empty($name)) 
        {
            $location = 'uploads/';

            if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name))
            {
                echo "hi";
                $filename = $_POST['filename'];
                $filepath = $location.$name;
                $advname = $_POST['advname'];
                $year = $_POST['year'];
                $cname = $_POST['cname'];
                $ctype = $_POST['ctype'];
                $sqlq = "INSERT INTO file(filename, filepath, advname, year, cname, ctype) VALUES ('".$filename."','".$filepath."','".$advname."','".$year."','".$cname."','".$ctype."');";
                $result = mysql_query($sqlq);
                if(!$result)
                {
                    die("Error in connecting to database!");
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

There seems to be a problem in the

```
if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name))
```

statement. This condition is evaluated as false.

Comment: What has changed on your server? Have you looked in the error log on your server

Comment: can't see anything wrong here really. Make sure your form's using a POST method with the right enctype, the input's got the right name attribute and the folder has the right permissions to write to it. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: I notice that you capture potential upload errors in `$error = $_FILES['ufile']['error'];` but you never actually see if there is an error code in there! Maybe that would shed some light on your issue

Comment: what `$_POST['filename']` contains

Comment: @Fred-ii- I changed back to 'tmp_name' in the $tmp_name variable. But when I echo it, it is empty.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I get 1 as the output when I echo $error.

Comment: @MeeneshJain filename is a custom file name input that I am getting in my form.

Comment: Dear god --- [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) an error 1 means something **Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.** I would have bet money on this being the issue

Comment: @Fred-ii- Error reporting returned nothing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Whats the odds of the OP just doing a powder on this question as well, without so much as a "bye, and thanks for all the fish"

Comment: @RiggsFolly *Hm...*, looking at their question history, I'd say 50 to 1. I'd bet a dollar on those odds, sure ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- So I guess I can thank you for the upvote! And you get yer $50

Comment: @RiggsFolly *You're welcome* ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$_FILES['ufile']['error']` gives you a value of 1 then the  `upload_max_filesize` in your config is set to a smaller value that the file you are trying to upload.

You cannot change the `upload_max_filesize` from within your code.

If you have access to your `php.ini`, `.htaccess`, `httpd.conf` or `.user.ini` you can change this value in any of those files.

So you would need to add or modify the parameter from its default of 2M (2meg)

```
upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

Its also a good idea to check the `post_max_size` at the same time as this may also have an effect on the max size of the file uploaded, make sure `post_max_size` is larger than `upload_max_filesize` as this should allow extra space for the other fields that you will be uploading as part of the post

Comment: You can put the 50 in the cash till ;-) maybe I'll pick in it every once in a while to get me a cappuccino and a cinnamon danish. You're welcome to join me lol

Comment: Now I am going to have to go and make a sandwich, you have made me hungry.

Comment: There's always some good that comes out of comments ;-) beit code or munchies solutions. Buon appetito!